# How do I find "Could not resolve placeholder" cause

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, junit

I am looking for an approach, rather than an answer.

I have an existing, working Spring "server" project, maven directory structure, including JUnit tests.  I also have an existing "library" project, different directory tree than the server project, used by the server project and by other server projects.

I am attempting to move some classes from the server project to the library project.  I used eclipse's refactor move function, since it searches java and XML files and seems to do a good job of altering what needs to be altered.  I got the classes moved over and corrected compilation mistakes.

However, now I have JUnit tests in the server project that are failing, and I can't figure out why.  The errors are all "could not resolve placeholder", and refer to fields in the moved classes that use an "@Value" annotation, things like:

```
@Value("x.y.maxRetries")
private int allowedRetries;
```

None of these values are new -- I haven't changed the code in these classes at all -- so the configuration does have these values.  But it seems to be telling me it cannot find them.  The different names (maxRetries v allowedRetries) are intentional, that's the way they are, and working, in the server project.

If I switch back to the branch I had before I moved these, everything is fine.  The only difference between the branches is the location of the moved Java files.

The JUnit tests are not testing the moved classes directly; the moved classes are only used indirectly.  I.e., we might have a "ProcessOne" class, and a "ProcessOneTest" class, both in the server project, unmoved.  We also have a "SupportOne" class in the library.  Before moving, the JUnit ProcessOneTest class works fine; after moving SupportOne, the JUnit test throws this error.

The JUnit test class has `@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/spring/applicationContext-test.xml" }).  I would love to think I could correct things there somehow, but whatever directory that is, it seems to me it should be relative to the server project and therefore should not have changed.  And, again, the values in it have not changed.

So I'm not looking for someone to tell me what's wrong here.  But if someone has a method I could go through to figure it out, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Property placeholders are (typically) resolved from property files. Are those part of your new project? Obviously something is missing.

Comment: I don't think there can be anything "missing" per se.  I don't have any new project, I have a server project and a library project that existed before, and @Value annotations that existed before, and property files that existed before.  There are PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer beans for both the server and library, and their "locations" property is set to the same two values.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be 'fixed' by removing the 'scan' section of the applicationContext-test.xml file in the server project.  It turned out the scan was not needed, and evidently something about having components that used to be scanned but are now not caused some kind of problem.  We're still not sure why this was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try full text search of "x.y.maxRetries" key in both server and library directories. Most likely you'll find the resource containing the key only in the server project.

Are the server beans managed by different Spring context than the library beans?  If they are, the placeholder configurer in the library context probably doesn't reference a resource containig the right keys.

Comment: The only occurrence of x.y.maxRetries is in one properties file; this file is referenced in the applicationContext-test.xml, under the property "locations", in both the server and library projects.  By 'spring context' do you mean the @ContextConfiguration ?  they are different files, though both load the same properties file containing the value(s) that I need.  I don't know if that could still be the problem...